Pipeline when using Group-by "plug-in" with more than 1000, it fails
When I run a pipeline with a "group by" with more than 1000 records, it fails. If the same pipeline has only 59 records It succeeds Any clues? Master Machine Type:e2,Number of masters:1,Master Cores:2,Master Memory (GB):8,Master Disk Size(GB):1000,Worker Cores:2,Worker Memory (GB):8,Worker Disk Size (GB):200,Worker Machine Type: e2
Increased resources at Executor in terms of memory to 6144 and CPU to 4.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
